# Pebble watchface crashes immediately upon installation

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm trying to follow the [Pebble C watchface tutorial](http://developer.getpebble.com/getting-started/watchface-tutorial/part3/), and I can get the time to display, but I can't get any weather information to show up. Looking at the logs, it appears that there is a fatal error immediately upon startup:

```
[INFO    ] Enabling application logging...
[INFO    ] Displaying logs ... Ctrl-C to interrupt.
[INFO    ] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/tools/pebblecomm/pebble.py", line 777, in _reader
    self._ws_client.handle_response(endpoint, resp)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'handle_response'

[INFO    ] <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'handle_response'
[ERROR   ] Lost connection to Pebble
```

I even have a log message as the very first line of code in the `main` function, but it doesn't display:

```
int main(void) {
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "Main.");
    init();
    app_event_loop();
    deinit();
}
```

I'm also getting a concerning warning upon building that might be related:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/pebble-sdk/3.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Does anyone know what might be happening? The total lack of any logs makes me think that my watchface code is not related to the crash. I can post some code if requested, though.

EDIT: I tried again with another project, with all of the code copy-pasted from Pebble's [tutorial source code](https://gist.github.com/pebble-gists/9b9d50b990d742a3ae34). Same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't your fault. This is an issue with the commandline tool. Upgrading to the latest SDK should fix this.

```
brew update
brew upgrade pebble-sdk
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this once I'm back to my work machine.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. Should I try switching entirely to CloudPebble in the meantime?

Comment: Before doing that I would also try doing `pebble wipe` and `pebble login`. If that fails then try CP. Good news though, the next release of the SDK tool is completely rewritten!

Comment: The logging tool is still breaking, unfortunately. For all I know it could be my phone's fault, since it's really old and not working 100%. I'll keep an eye out for the next SDK release. Thanks!

Comment: Darn. Go ahead and send an email to devsupport@getpebble.com.